# According to System Information I have one processor and 2 cores, but when I open the 'CPU-usage' window in Activity Monitor I see 4 graphs

Tags: cpu, activity-monitor, system-information

What does this 4 graphs mean and how are they related to my 2 cores?
I have a MacBook Pro (13 inch medio 2012?
[image: System Information]
[image: CPU-usage window]

Comment: can you add an image ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a multi-threaded CPU. Your computer has one processor, with two physical cores, and two virtual threads on each core. So to the computer it sees four cores/threads available. This makes it easier for load balancing and sharing of the CPU between processes. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)) Wikipedia article.

Comment: I'm using macports, but I changed its preferences to so it can execute 2 jobs (commands) at the time because I have two cores (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352419/why-does-macports-take-forever-to-build-simple-packages)
Can i upgrade this to 4 then?

Comment: Yes you could, however your jump from two to four will not be as impressive as your jump from one to two. Since you have four threads/two cores it offers a performance improvement, but not as much as having four separate cores. Also the rest of your system may slow down as all threads will be busy while you're using MacPorts, but MacPorts will finish sooner, so it's a trade off in either direction.